# can't get array key after i json_decode it

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, key

i json_decode ed an array, even thought i can print_r it, i cant call its keys. Im not a pro nor nothing, so any help is welcome. I tried a lot of things, but i cant get it to work.

My goal is to present the array results i a way that is easy to read, so I want to access it in the HTML part, and not only to be printed.

the array that i get after print_r is: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [pda] => 41.52258509711 [upa] => 51.345212698165 [uu] => www.chevrolet.com.ar/ ) )

```
<?php

$accessID = "xxxxx";
$secretKey = "xxxxx";
// Set your expires times for several minutes into the future.
// An expires time excessively far in the future will not be honored by the Mozscape API.
$expires = time() + 300;
// Put each parameter on a new line.
$stringToSign = $accessID."\n".$expires;
// Get the "raw" or binary output of the hmac hash.
$binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $stringToSign, $secretKey, true);
// Base64-encode it and then url-encode that.
$urlSafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));

$cols = "103079215108";
// Put it all together and you get your request URL.
$requestUrl = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/?Cols=".$cols."&AccessID=".$accessID."&Expires=".$expires."&Signature=".$urlSafeSignature;
// Put your URLS into an array and json_encode them.
$batchedDomains = array('xxxxxxxx.com');
$encodedDomains = json_encode($batchedDomains);
// Use Curl to send off your request.
// Send your encoded list of domains through Curl's POSTFIELDS.
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $encodedDomains
    );
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
$contents = json_decode($content);

print_r($contents);


$pageAuthority=$contents->upa;
$domainAuthority = $contents->pda;
$theUrl = $contents->uu;

?>

<html>
<body>
    <h1>MOZcape API</h1>
<ul>
    <li>URL: <?php echo $theUrl; ?></li>
    <li>PA: <?php echo $pageAuthority; ?></li>
    <li>DA: <?php echo $domainAuthority; ?></li>

    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you'll need to post that `$contents` contain, from there, the contents of that array can be examined.

Comment: I guess what you said is really easy, but I still dont get it. Is too much to ask for an example? Thank you for your time and sorry for asking this kingd of questions.

Comment: Edit your question here showing the result of the `print_r($contents);`.

Comment: Done!, i dont know how I can get that but then i can call its keys. It must be something super simple, but cant make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to change $contents = json_decode($content);

to $contents = json_decode($content, true); so it can be an array.

Then call it with:$pageAuthority=$contents[0]["upa"];

Instead of:$pageAuthority=$contents->upa;